# How access to inner same classname div with different idname in HTML data using Jsoup in android

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse data from HTML.I need to get the all names from inner div class=vacancy-item which has different idnames.
Below please See the HTML code

```
<section class="home-vacancies" id="vacancy_wrapper">
<div class="home-block-title">job openings</div>
<div class="vacancy-filter">
    ...................
</div>
<div class="vacancy-wrapper">
    <div class="vacancy-item" data-id="9120">
        ..............
    </div>
    <div class="vacancy-item" data-id="9119">
        ..................
    </div>
    <div class="vacancy-item" data-id="9118">
        ................................
    </div>
    <div class="vacancy-item" data-id="9117">
        .............................
    </div>
```

Here is my code:
Please help.

```
       doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
       //title = doc.select(".page-content div:eq(3)");
       title = doc.getElementsByClass("div[class=vacancy-wrapper]");
       titleList.clear();
       for (Element titles : title) {     
            String text = titles.getElementsB("vacancy-item").text();
            titleList.add(text);
       }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only query for a `class` attribute with `getElementByClass`, e.g. `getElementByClass("vacancy-wrapper")` would work.

You will also need a second loop to get each `vacancy-item`s text as a separate element:

```
Elements title = doc.getElementsByClass("vacancy-wrapper");
for (Element titles : title) {
    Elements items = titles.getElementsByClass("vacancy-item");
    for (Element item : items) {
        String text = item.text();
        // process text
    }
}
```

An other option would be to use Jsoup's `select` method:

```
Elements es = doc.select("div.vacancy-wrapper div.vacancy-item");
for (Element vi : es) {
    String text = vi.text());
    // process text
}
```

This would select all `div` elements with a `class` attribute `vacancy-item` that are under a `div` with a `class` attribute `vacancy-wrapper`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. I have tried both your suggestions. In my case i don know why, Elements es = doc.select("div.vacancy-wrapper div.vacancy-item"); does not  get the item that i nedded, it doesn't do anything. I write it in this way for (Element titles : title) {              // и в цикле захватываем все данные какие есть на странице
                    String text = titles.text();
                    Log.i("++++",text);
                    titleList.add(titles.text()); } but nothing happens

Comment: maybe the problem comes from HTML section class="home-vacancies" its mmain part of my page.
When i use select in following way
title = doc.select(".page-content div:eq(3)");  i got some items, but i cann't find this items in HTML file, i don't know where they come from

Comment: @Hakob M can you check if your `div`s are generated by some script on the page or part of the returned html

Comment: no my divs are part of HTML URL page.My divs does not generated by script.

Comment: @HakobM the sample HTML you provided works for me (jsoup-1.8.3) -the `.page-content div:eq(3)` returns nothing. Can you test with your sample from a local file (or a string) - maybe your actual page output is slightly different

Comment: i use jsoup-1.8.3 also, it returns me null , it cann't find nothing
Can i send you my code?

Comment: it looks like some divs are visible for jsoup some are not

Comment: @HakobM can you update your question and provide an link to your page or to the full HTML. You could also try http://try.jsoup.org/ with the full HTML

Comment: here is HTML page HR.am
i want to parse jobs date, using Jsoup, to accese job date i need to accese to div class=vacancy-wrapper,  all the other divs inside of this div are jobs

Comment: @HakobM when you open the page (using *View Page Source* **not** Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools) you will see that there is an **empty** `<div class="vacancy-wrapper">` element. This element gets populated by a script on page load. Now, Jsoup will only be able to read/parse the raw HTML, scripts that change the page's DOM will **not** be executed

Comment: ya i saw it ,that is the reason why i'm getting null result by printing output in my terminal actually i'm viewing html code by Inspect Element, in this way <div class="vacancy-wrapper"> is not empty )), that is my mistake, thanks a lot for help.
 I'm new in app development, and this is my first project that i want to do to use my knowledges.
What you can suggest me to do? How can i access to <div class="vacancy-wrapper"> elements in this case?

Comment: That's an other thing entirely (and has probably do nothing to do with `Jsoup`). I'd suggest we end the discussion here and you post a new question with the proper description of the *new* problem.